# YUI Calendar, How can I implement it like the jQuery UI Calendar?

Tags: jquery, calendar, focus, yui, textfield

With jQuery UI I can simply use `.datePicker()` or similar and it will automatically attach it to the `focus` and `blur` events of a text field.

How can I do this with YUI calendar, sample code would be great!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start with sample code for that use case is here:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/calcontainer.html